# Is it possible to use a socket accepted on one PHP script on another?

Tags: java, php, sockets

I want to achieve something that might seem absurd.

I've created a PHP script that creates server socket. I'm able to connect to server socket from java client.

Now what I want is to maintain this socket at server side somewhere so that I can access it later on when needed.

But, the problem here is, as soon as the respond() function terminates, the socket is closed, and the br.readLine() method in Run class receives blank line.

For my purpose, the readLine() method should continue waiting for a response.

What I've done so far...

regsock.php
(Where registering of socket should happen)

```
  <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fh = fopen("reg.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fh, "SERVER Starting\r\n");
    $sersock = socket_create_listen(1234);
    fwrite($fh, "SERVER Running\r\n");

    while(true){
        respond();
    }

    function respond(){
        global $sersock, $fh;
        $sock = socket_accept($sersock);
        fwrite($fh, "Client Connected\r\n");
        echo "Client: ".socket_read($sock, 1024);
        socket_write($sock, "OK\n\r");

        //Some way to store client sockets?
    }
    socket_close($sersock);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Run.java

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

bw.write("Server OK?");
bw.flush();
System.out.println("Server:"+br.readLine()); //Output-> Server:OK
System.out.println("Server:"+br.readLine()); //Output-> Server:
bw.close();
br.close();
socket.close();
```

And, remote.php
(Where I want to access the socket accepted on resgsock.php)

```
<?php
    $sock = //Retrieve socket resource here
    fwrite($sock, "REMOTE PAGE\r\n");
    echo "Socket write complete";
?>
```

Is it even possible or I'm just doing everything wrong.

Can this be done through some other method.

Comment: On which operating system do you plan to run the PHP? Windows API for example has a function for passing sockets from one process to another, WSADuplicateSocket. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Joni : PHP is running on Linux

Answer (score 0):

The socket accepted in regsock.php can be passed to remote.php only if remote.php is executed in the same process as regsock, or in a subprocess.

For example you could do this:

```
# In global setup: handle child process termination automatically
# Might break calls to "system" though
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

function respond(){
    global $sersock, $fh;
    $sock = socket_accept($sersock);
    fwrite($fh, "Client Connected\r\n");
    echo "Client: ".socket_read($sock, 1024);
    socket_write($sock, "OK\n\r");

    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == 0) {
        # This is now a subprocess. If I "include" remote.php
        # it can operate on $sock as if it was its own.
        include "remote.php";
        # Now exit the subprocess
        exit;
    } elsif ($pid < 0) {
        # fork failed, handle error
    } else {
        echo "Subprocess running with pid $pid!";
        # Close the copy of the socket in parent process,
        # subprocess has a copy of its own.
        socket_close($sock);
    }

}
```

Comment: That would work even without forking another process because code from remote.php will be executed under respond() function.

I want remote.php to be accessed from a browser.

Comment: Okay, I have to find another way to facilitate communication then...

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could have "regsock" start a subprocess that waits for a connection from "remote" and after that just pipes data between the two sockets, but maybe there's an easier solution to the problem you were originally trying to solve.

Comment: @Joni: to be frank, this is the only solution I've found for this exact problem on the web. Thanks for posting the comment here! There's just one caveat: for some reason socket_listen can pipe only one message through to socket_send per connection.

Comment: @Everst after writing this answer I learned that you can pass open file descriptors from one process to another using ancillary data in UNIX domain sockets, but if you're using Java like the OP it might not be worth the trouble (no built-in support for UNIX sockets in Java). But if you post a question with the problem you have with socket_listen someone may help you with that

Comment: No, I am using PHP only but connecting to a device via OpenVPN. The problem is that some commands to the device might come from a different script and some should be initiated by the device itself: therefore, I need both listen and read (i.e. server+client in one). Unfortunately, pcntl_fork does not allow this behavior on Apache server - so, looking into pthreads now. I believe what you mean by UNIX domain sockets is that several scripts can access same .sock file? The only problem there is that I need to pass some arguments around.. Can you share any helpful link with regard to shared sock?

Comment: @Joni: FYI, you won't believe but socket_select() works magic and is the easiest ever implementation for this particular problem. Killed ages to find that one... Just in case you are interested.

Comment: It sounds like your situation is very different from the OP's: Process A has a socket that process B wants to use. UNIX does not allow that unless process A makes the socket explicitly available.